# Can't acces localhost through http://localhost/ on tomcat

Tags: web-server, tomcat, localhost

I am having trouble accessing localhost through

```
http://localhost 
and 
http://127.0.0.1
```

But i can access both when i use https.

```
 https://localhost
```

Why do you think this is? The web server is Tomcat 7.0.25.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably Tomcat is configured to listen only to HTTPS and not HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `http://` to connect to the server, unless otherwise stated as part of the url your browser will assume port `80`.

When you use `https://` to connect to the server, unless otherwise stated your browser will assume port `443`.

You can connect on port 443 but not on port 80.

- You have not configured your service to listen on port 80. ✔
- You have not configured a proxy for port 80 to your service.
- There is a firewall blocking port 80
- There is something else.

Comment: Thanks it was because my tomcats configuration was changed to use a different port number than 80, changing it back has solved it.